# How to implement a friendship relationship as a mutual subscription in the Prisma ORM schema?

Tags: javascript, database, orm, nestjs, prisma

I started with such a scheme where users are connected by a [many-to-many relationship](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations#many-to-many-self-relations):

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model User {
  id              String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  followers       User[]   @relation("UserFollows", fields: [followerIds], references: [id])
  followerIds     String[] @map("follower_ids") @db.ObjectId
  subscriptions   User[]   @relation("UserFollows", fields: [subscriptionIds], references: [id])
  subscriptionIds String[] @map("subscription_ids") @db.ObjectId
}
```

And maintaining these connections is quite easy:

```js
export class UsersService {
  constructor(private readonly prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async subscribeUser(followerId: string, subscriptionId: string) {
    await this.prisma.user.update({
      where: { id: followerId },
      data: { subscriptions: { connect: { id: subscriptionId } } },
    });

    return {
      message: 'User successfully subscribed',
    };
  }
}
```

But in this case, how can we implement and maintain a friendship-as-mutual-subscription relationship between them?

What's the best way to solve this problem without constantly recalculating the mutual intersection of these arrays?